# Delete all files in inside folder

Tags: powershell

I create a PowerShell command that have to remove on my diskstation all files inside folders which contains the word "rendery". Everything would be fine, if the command deleted the files in the folder containing the word "rendery", because the script currently deletes the folder (along with the files that are inside) that contains the word "rendery".

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Test -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.Name -match "rendery"} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert another `Get-ChildItem` call after `Where-Object` to resolve only the child items of the target folders:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Test -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -match "rendery"} | Get-ChildItem | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Note that `$_.PSIsContainer` is already a boolean value, so you can shorten `$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true` to just `$_.PSIsContainer`

Comment: works! Thanks a lot. I also try to delete files older than X days but I dont know where to put the code. Anyway I get error everytime { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15) }

Comment: @Mikel_ That sounds like it conflicts with `Remove-Item -Recurse` - you can't ask PowerShell to both "delete everything under here" and also only delete specific items :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Have a nice day.